# C++ operator= overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have struct `Token`, to which I'm trying assign operator=. I wanna be able to assign to char. I tried `char operator=(const Token& token){ return token.kind; }`, which throws error, says is not unary operator, tried `char operator=(const char& ch, const Token& token){ return token.kind; }` didn't help either. Yes I can do just `char ch { token.kind };`, but I wanna do it through operator in case if add some logic. Can you help me?

[REPL EXAMPLE](https://repl.it/@RamzanChasygov/MuffledVeneratedMass)

```
struct Token {
  char kind;
  int value;

  Token(char kind, int value): kind(kind), value(value){}:
}
```

Comment: Please present a complete example that readers that can try out.

Comment: You want `Token::operator char() const;` in in your token class.  Beware this can give unexpected results.  Prefer `Token::as_char() const;` instead.

Comment: For the record, that explicit conversion is (IMO) much better. Adding implicit conversions to primitive types is the route to madness. Your logic that you want to give `Token` the power to decide how the conversion should be performed is reasonable, so a conversion operator makes some sense... but at least make it `explicit`!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't overload [`operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Overloaded_operators) for built-in types like `char`, to allow assign `Token` to `char`. `operator=` must be overloaded as member function.

As the workaround, you can add a [conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), which allows implicit conversion from `Token` to `char`. Note that implicit conversion might cause potential issues, e.g. it allows to pass a `Token` to a function which expects a `char`.

```
struct Token {
  char kind;
  int value;

  Token(char kind, int value): kind(kind), value(value){}
  operator char() const { return kind; }
};
```

BTW: You can make the conversion function `explicit`, to avoid the issues of implicit conversion. And then in the assignment from `Token` to `char` you have to apply explicit conversion, like `c = static_cast<char>(token);`.

Comment: but why I can't use operator=, if c++ allows you, or is it only can return `Token`?

Comment: @RamzanChasygov read the relevant part of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: @RamzanChasygov You can't overload `operator=` to accomplish this, I added some explanations at the beginning. And you can get more from the link I posted.

Comment: @songyuanyao Sorry, I did't see it

Comment: @RamzanChasygov That's fine, I added it later.

Comment: For a bonus point recommend `explicit` (if supported) to fix the implicit conversion "problem".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: but what if instead of struct I have enum? Is it possible to add conversation function?

Comment: @RamzanChasygov You can't add conversion function to enum, afaik. Unscoped enum could implictly convert to integral types, while scoped enum only supports explicit conversion.